# createContainer() and events defined in GUI builder

Tags: codenameone

I've created a blank container in the GUI builder.
With the GUI builder I've attached an event on post Show event of the container.

When I create the container with:

`Container c = createContainer( fetchResourceFile(), "MycontainterName" );
f.addComponent( c );`

The event method is never fired.

What to do to fire the event?

The same apply for events defined on components in the container: they are never fired.

Answer (score 0):

Events fire on forms but with `createContainer` it becomes impossible to track the usage of a component.

I'm guessing that what you are trying to accomplish is doable with `EmbeddedContainer` which will allow you embed a `Container` into a parent form.

Comment: In order to add embed a Container, I've added an EmbeddedContainer in my form. But I'd like to change it's content on code. I've tryed with findEmbeddedContainer().setEmbed( "MycontainterName" ); but it doesn't display the container. But if I set the Embed value in GUI builder to the "MycontainterName" container it works. Is there something else to do to correctly embed the container?

Comment: You can use the Container.replace() call to replace the content of the container. Normally however, if you have a navigation command within the embedded container it will implicitly replace the content "in place"

Comment: OK but the problem is that events (defined on button action, on post show, etc.) are not fired. I use this code : Container embed = createContainer( fetchResourceFile(), "MycontainterName" ); ct.replace( oldcontainer, embed, CommonTransitions.createSlide( CommonTransitions.SLIDE_HORIZONTAL, false, 200 ) ); but this don't work. I'm able to call the post show event by calling postShowContainer( embed ); but I don't think that's the best way to do it...

Comment: If you use createContainer and don't use show to show the container listeners won't be bound. You will need to find your own components and use action listener etc. to bind to them. If you use show or standard navigation then the event biding should be seamless.

Comment: I've tried to use showContainer() but I can't achieve what I want. First the action events aren't fired. Second the container couldn't be embedded inside another container (or I can't find how to do this). So I use createContainer and then add the call addActionListener() on components that need it.

Comment: Originally when we designed the embedded container the navigation commands were within that container and so when a user clicked a button with a command from within that container navigation happened seamlessly there.